# Play Framework: No output shown in the browser

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I just started out with the "Play for Java" book. Was doing some of their code examples. I'm seeing some warning in my list.scala.html file about some

> Invalid text String and character used in @for(product <- products) {

When I go to localhost:9000/products/ -> I just get a blank screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to explain the issue better since I'm new to this... ask me if you need more input.

Answer (score 3):

'Blank page' is not clear enough, you need to know if your page is rendered at all (so it's showing but has no content) or if nothing happens.

You have two ways: insert some element always visible on the begining of the view ie: `<h1>Producsts</h1>` second thing is that you should always check source of rendered page in the browser, to see if typical parts as `<!DOCTYPE html>` are in proper place.

Anyway on your screenshots I see at least two mistakes:

1. You don't ... render the view at all, `ok()` just returns *empty* Result with status `200` (which for browser means: *That's ok - server said, that no content is proper in this place*). Use this instead:

   ```
   return ok(views.html.list.render(products)); 
   // Where 'products' is Set<Product> filled probably from your DB
   ```
2. You are trying to duplicate  `<!DOCTYPE html>`, while it's probably declared in `main.scala.html` before, so your result HTML will be invalid.

In working with web frameworks it's good practice to learn typical inspection tools in web browser, and if page *doesn't look* as you expected you should go to the source view and check the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Import necessary fules;

```
    import play.mvc.Controller;
    import play.mvc.Result;
    import models.Product;
    import java.util.List;
    import views.html.products.list;
```

The list method of the controller would be like the following:

```
    public static Result list(){
        List<Product> products = Product.findAll();
        return ok(list.render(products));
    }
```